# Access the Application object inside a Window class in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Can we access the current System.Windows.Application object inside a Window class in WPF ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes sure. You can access it everywhere in a WPF application.

```
// assuming that you derivate of Application is named App
((App)Application.Current).SomePropertyOfApp = ...
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes - it's as easy as [Application.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.current.aspx).